# How to implement array.any() and array.all() methods in Coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript

How to implement `array.any()` and `array.all()` methods in Coffeescript?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Those are actually part of [Javascript 1.6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.6) and will work just the same in CoffeeScript. You want [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

I don't know what environment you're in, but IE < 9 doesn't seem to support those methods. They're pretty easy to add. There's a snippet of code on those pages that show you compatibility code and if you want you can translate them to CoffeeScript, though you [don't have to](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#embedded).

A cruder, simpler way would be (untested):

```
if not Array.prototype.some
    Array.prototype.some = (f) -> (x for x in @ when f(x)).length > 0

if not Array.prototype.every
    Array.prototype.every = (f) -> (x for x in @ when f(x)).length == @length
```

But neither of those have short circuit logic. **Edit**: But see Ricardo's answer for a better version of them.

Comment: Perfect answer. I'd just add that one can use underscore.js for compatibility with older browsers, as the answer below says.

Comment: It's easy to add short-circuiting, and you forgot `?=`, see my answer :)

Comment: @Ricardo - Yeah, that is better. Also, I didn't know ?= trick, so that's pretty neat.

Comment: Polishing the above:
`Array.prototype.some ?= (f) -> return true for x in @ when f(x)`

Answer (score 12):

Short-circuited (optimized) versions:

```
Array.prototype.some ?= (f) ->
  (return true if f x) for x in @
  return false

Array.prototype.every ?= (f) ->
  (return false if not f x) for x in @
  return true
```

The `?=` is for "existential assignment", only runs when that property is `null`/`undefined`.

Answer (score 6):

Check out [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/), which provides you with `_.any` and `_.all` methods (a.k.a. `_.some` and `_.every`) that will run in any major JS environment. Here's how they're implemented in CoffeeScript in [underscore.coffee](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/documentation/docs/underscore.html):

```
_.some = (obj, iterator, context) ->
  iterator ||= _.identity
  return obj.some iterator, context if nativeSome and obj.some is nativeSome
  result = false
  _.each obj, (value, index, list) ->
    _.breakLoop() if (result = iterator.call(context, value, index, list))
  result

_.every = (obj, iterator, context) ->
  iterator ||= _.identity
  return obj.every iterator, context if nativeEvery and obj.every is nativeEvery
  result = true
  _.each obj, (value, index, list) ->
    _.breakLoop() unless (result = result and iterator.call(context, value, index, list))
  result
```

(These depend on `_.each`, which is a straightforward iteration method, and `_.breakLoop`, which just throws an exception.)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at this today and decided to implement `all` as a fold, and I suppose you could do the same for `any` as well (but it doesn't short circuit, either):

```
all = (someArray, predicate) ->
  reduceAll = (left, right) ->
    return left and right
  return [predicate(elem) for elem in someArray].reduce(reduceAll, true)
```

The non-short-circuiting `any` would be mostly similar:

```
reduceAny = (left, right) ->
    return left or right
[p(elem) for elem in someArray].reduce(reduceAny, false)
```

I did `all` this way because I found it to be readable. Also, I just did it as a free-floating function instead of an array method.